# How can i set next hop of nodes in NS2?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a sensor field with dimension 200*200.
I choose nearest node to center of field as a cluster head.
My goal is that data of sensors forward to cluster head and cluster head forward data to sink node. 
I want cluster head become next hop of any sensor nodes (apart from sink node) in field.
How do i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ns2 but if there is a forwarding command then it should be just a matter of looping the nodes and running the forward command.  Here's some pseudo code.

```
set head_x 7
set head_y 8

# get node at head_y head_x as head_node
# tell head to forward to sinc node

for {set y 0} {$y < 200} {incr y} {

    for {set x 0} {$x < 200} {incr x} {

        if {$x != $head_x && $y != $head_y} {
            # tell node $y $x to forward to $head_node
        }

    }
}
```